# Write to a CV::Mat from a higher scope within a function

Tags: c++

I've written this function to read matrices from the ROS parameter server.

```
void read_matrix_from_param(ros::NodeHandle nodehandle, std::string param, cv::Mat &cv_matrix) {
      // 1D vector for temporarily holding matrix elements
      std::vector<double> _data;

      // matrix dimensions
      int _rows, _cols;

      // read from param server
      nodehandle.getParam(param + std::string("/data"), _data);
      nodehandle.getParam(param + std::string("/rows"), _rows);
      nodehandle.getParam(param + std::string("/cols"), _cols);

      // create cv::Mat and copy into cv_matrix
      cv::Mat(_rows, _cols, CV_64F, _data.data()).copyTo(cv_matrix);
  }
```

called like this:

```
cv::Mat test_matrix1, test_matrix2;
read_matrix_from_param(private_nh, std::string("camera_matrix"), test_matrix1);
read_matrix_from_param(private_nh, std::string("distortion_coefficients"), test_matrix2);
```

This works as expected but my editor gives me a style-guide warning for the function signature.

```
runtime/references: Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer: cv::Mat &cv_matrix
```

So how should this be done? I have tried to do as the style-guide suggests but been unable to get working code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the matrix is always empty when passed into the function, the more normal way to write this would be to avoid any side effects and make cv_matrix the return type. i.e

```
cv::Mat read_matrix_from_param(ros::NodeHandle nodehandle, const std::string& param)
{
    cv::Mat cv_matrix

    ...
    return cv_matrix;
}
```

As a side point you should pass in param and possibly nodehandle, as const & to avoid unnecessary copies.

If this is not the case and you may pass in non-empty matrices ( I think that wouldn't make sense here ), then I would say using a non-const ref is fine. Alternative you could use a pointer i.e.

```
void read_matrix_from_param(ros::NodeHandle nodehandle, std::string param, cv::Mat *cv_matrix)
{
    ...

    cv::Mat(_rows, _cols, CV_64F, _data.data()).copyTo(*cv_matrix);
}
```

called as

`read_matrix_from_param(private_nh, std::string("camera_matrix"), &test_matrix1);`

Personally I wouldn't use a pointer and [Core C++ Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-conventional) recommends a reference, but looks like it is the style recommended by google see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299021/non-optional-pointers-vs-non-const-references-in-c . If you are using clang-tidy google style guidelines are an option in that I believe so that may be where this warning is coming from.